# color picker for each list item not showing up correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, color-picker, spectrumjs

I am trying to assign random color within a color picker container to each item in the list, with a container button (color picker container) in front of each so that on click the color picker container opens up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(obj) {
        $('#myList').data('types', obj.types.map(function(o) {
            // console.log(o.type);
            return o.type;
        })).append(obj.types.map(function(o) {
            return '<li>' + o.type + '</li>';
        }).join('')).spectrum({
            color: (function(m,s,c){return (c ? arguments.callee(m,s,c-1) : '#') +
                s[m.floor(m.random() * s.length)]})(Math,'0123456789ABCDEF',5),
            preferredFormat: "rgb",
            showInput: true,
            showPalette: true,
            showAlpha: true,
            palette: [["red", "rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)"]]
        });
    });
});
```

the problem is, the  button is not showing up in front of each list item, and it ONLY shows up when I click on the list item and the color is the same for each item.
however the goal is to generate the random color for each item.

could somebody tell me where the problem is and how can I fix the issue?

### update

here is the color picker I am using:
https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum

### 2nd update:

here is the jsfiddle, but I couldn't pass my data into the getJSON, because in the original file, i read a json file with the same structure that I have provided in the example.
https://jsfiddle.net/6j936afx/

### 3rd update:

here is the html code that the list goes into:

```
<div class="item-group">
 <label class="item-label">Types</label>
    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="myList"></ul>    
</div>
```

I think I need to inject a class that will hold the color picker container in each list item, if so, how can I do it directly in the javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add plugin on li elements after they are added to Dom

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON("data.json", function (obj) {
                    $('#myList').data('types', obj.types.map(function (o) {
                        // console.log(o.type);
                        return o.type;
                    })).append(obj.types.map(function (o) {
                        return '<li>' + o.type + '</li>';
                    }).join(''));

                    $("#mylist li").spectrum({
                        color: (function (m, s, c) {
                            return (c ? arguments.callee(m, s, c - 1) : '#') +
                                    s[m.floor(m.random() * s.length)]
                        })(Math, '0123456789ABCDEF', 5),
                        preferredFormat: "rgb",
                        showInput: true,
                        showPalette: true,
                        showAlpha: true,
                        palette: [["red", "rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)"]]
                    });
                });
            });
```

For random color you should use each()

```
$("#mylist li").each(function(){
                       $(this).spectrum({
                        color: (function (m, s, c) {
                            return (c ? arguments.callee(m, s, c - 1) : '#') +
                                    s[m.floor(m.random() * s.length)]
                        })(Math, '0123456789ABCDEF', 5),
                        preferredFormat: "rgb",
                        showInput: true,
                        showPalette: true,
                        showAlpha: true,
                        palette: [["red", "rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)"]]
                    });
                });
```

**Edit:**
Add a input in each li and then add plug-in to it like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("data.json", function (obj) {
                $('#myList').data('types', obj.types.map(function (o) {
                    // console.log(o.type);
                    return o.type;
                })).append(obj.types.map(function (o) {
                    return '<li>' + o.type + '<input class="color-picker" type="text"/></li>';
                }).join(''));

                $("#mylist .color-picker").each(function(){
                   $(this).spectrum({
                    color: (function (m, s, c) {
                        return (c ? arguments.callee(m, s, c - 1) : '#') +
                                s[m.floor(m.random() * s.length)]
                    })(Math, '0123456789ABCDEF', 5),
                    preferredFormat: "rgb",
                    showInput: true,
                    showPalette: true,
                    showAlpha: true,
                    palette: [["red", "rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)"]]
                   });
                });

            });
        });
```

Comment: your li elements added to list or not ?

Comment: I still see my elements of the list, but I don't see the colorpicker container for each item, and the randomization is not fixed for each list item.

Comment: your new edit works, the randomization is working now, but the color picker is not visible in front of each list item. It shows up only on click on the text of the each list item. How can I show the color picker container in front of each ?

Comment: if they are in the DOM, why aren't they visible in front of the list item? how to make them visible?

Comment: Make option flat: true, to make palate visiable 
See this http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#modes-flat

Comment: **flat** makes the whole color picker container to be visible, I just want to show the small container in front of each list item text. Like here https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#methods-set  as it is in front of the input text box.

Comment: yes, it is working thanks. however i need to add styling to align the color picker to the right. do you have any idea? inside the javascript? sorry i am newbie to javascript and struggling during my first days. I added align="right" inside the input element in the javascript, but not working

Comment: Use class given inside input tag to align it properly. like in my example i give color-picker class to input tag

Comment: you mean adding this to my stylesheet: `.color-picker{
    align-items: right;
}` i did this but not working.

Comment: .color-picker{ align-items: right; } this is not working because it add a custom div there with class sp-replacer. Try to play with this like .sp-replacer{ float:right}

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with the specific plugin but if you want one in each list item my guess would be you would want `children()` in that chain so you apply it to each `<li>` and not to the parent list.

Try

```
$('#myList').data('types', obj.types.map(function(o) {
            // console.log(o.type);
            return o.type;
        })).append(obj.types.map(function(o) {
            return '<li>' + o.type + '</li>';
        }).join('')).children().spectrum({....
```

If this works then expand it with an `each` so each instance gets it's own random color

```
....children().each(function(){
    $(this).spectrum({/*opts*/})

})
```

Comment: i tried this , but it is not working. I would appreciate if you could suggest an answer with any other color picker plugin. it is acceptable.

Comment: What did it do? I just updated with a single instance `each` version also. As far as colorpickers go there are lots of them around, easily found in a web search

Comment: yes, the randomization is NOW working on each list item. thanks, but I still can't show the colorpicker container in front of each list item. i should only click on it to make it show up. how can this be fixed?

Comment: You will need to dig through the options and docs of the plugin

Comment: i don't think it is a problem of plugin. it is just a javascript question of how to inject the container into the list item. should I add a separate class into html to capture it? or directly in the javascript?

Comment: That likely depends on how the plugin is configured. I quite honestly don't plan to read through all the docs and options since I don't even have a demo to test it on nor the time to tweak it. That's part of configuring plugins when you aren't totally familiar with them and sometimes you end up completely switching to a different one even

Comment: Note that if you need different elements within the `<li>` do it within your `append()` function where you create each `<li>` and modify the selector using `find()`

Comment: anyway thanks for the comment and the answer, i will try to figure out how to do it as you told me. cheers